# Bash script, string spaces handling

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I'm writing a script that will automatically sort my albums on my NAS server and encountered the following error. Whenever I have a space in an album name I'm getting an error. Albums can be either called "Artist_-_Album" or "Artist One - Album"

```
  #!/bin/bash
  for file in /home/peres/Documents/*
  do
    name=$(basename "$file")
    number=${#name}

  #sort if artist and album contains "_-_"

    if [[ $name == *"_-_"* ]]
    then
            echo "Album detected!"
            artistname=${name%%_-_*}
            albumname=${name##*_-_}
            mkdir -p $name/$albumname
            mv $name $artistname
    fi


  #sort if artist and album contains " - "

    if [[ $name == *" - "* ]]
    then
            echo "Album detected!"
            artistname=${name%% - *}
            albumname=${name##* - }
            mkdir -p $name/$albumname
            mv $name $artistname
    fi
  done
```

Comment: Put double quotes in all variables like $name to "$name"

Comment: I tried many things, this one doesn't work either